# Bluetooth service not starting automatically

Tags: bluetooth, 20.04, blueman

Whenever I run this command It shows an error showing that Bluetooth adapters were not installed...

```
sudo blueman-manager
```

When I run this command and run Blueman-manger again it works properly.

```
sudo /etc/init.d/bluetooth start
```

Can someone tell me what is wrong? what can I do so that I every time don't have to activate Bluetooth service manually?
I'm using ubuntu 20.04 LTS.

Comment: Try ```sudo systemctl enable bluetooth.service``` and reboot.